# Spark Kryo Registrator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I'm using kryo as serializer in spark 2.1 I have set registration as required but I have facing a problem, I can't register this class:

`org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningAwareFileIndex$SerializableFileStatus$SerializableBlockLocation[]`

I have tried with `classOf[Array[Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningAwareFileIndex$SerializableFileStatus$SerializableBlockLocation").type]]` and other combinations but I don't succeed in the registration of  this class.

I have tried as well creating a java class like register and registering the class as 
    `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningAwareFileIndex$SerializableFileStatus$SerializableBlockLocation[].class;`

Any clue is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my question, I've used:

kryo.register(ClassTag(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PartitioningAwareFileIndex$SerializableBlockLocation")).wrap.runtimeClass)

It allows register for the class name at runtime wrapped in an array.